# Как изменять цвет в Unity Editor`e? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Заранее всем спасибо <3 Я вот начал изучать Unity Editor и вот столкнулся с проблемой, каким образом можно изменить цвет либо текста либо фона поля. В Style`ах нету параметра цвета только размер шрифт и тд. тп. Я прошу вас о помощи. Если что-то не понятно задавайте наводящие вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Поле это InputField? Если да, то можно через image менять:

```
_inputField.image.color = Color.white;
```